# Perl library path/s

Tags: perl, module, find, locate

I need to find the location of my perl library/libraries how can I do this? 
Something similar to what this gives you for python...

```
python -c "import sys; print sys.path"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print the contents of the `@INC` variable:

```
perl -e 'print "@INC\n";'
```

`@INC` contains all the paths that Perl will search to find a module.

Answer (score 2):

The physical location of loaded modules are in the [`%INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25INC) hash:

> - `%INC`
>
>   The hash `%INC` contains entries for each filename included via the [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html), [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html), or [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) operators. The key is the filename you specified (with module names converted to pathnames), and the value is the location of the file found. The `require` operator uses this hash to determine whether a particular file has already been included.
>
>   If the file was loaded via a hook (e.g. a subroutine reference, see [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) for a description of these hooks), this hook is by default inserted into `%INC` in place of a filename. Note, however, that the hook may have set the `%INC` entry by itself to provide some more specific info.

Usage demonstrated for a random module on my system:

```
$ perl -MFile::Slurp -e 'print $INC{"File/Slurp.pm"}'
/Users/miller/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.0/lib/site_perl/5.20.0/File/Slurp.pm
```

Answer (score 2):

List all places where modules will be looked for: `perl -E 'say for @INC'`

List all the actual files modules have been loaded from: `perl -E 'say for keys %INC'`